# Why do the excerpts for these tags appear different?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki

I was doing some tag wiki editing using the [Tags page](https://superuser.com/tags), and I noticed this discrepancy between the excerpts on the [visual-studio-2012](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) tag.

This is what I see when I don't hover over the tag:
[image: unhovered]

And when I do:
[image: hovered]

Aren't these supposed to be the same?

Comment: Related http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/excerpt-not-starting-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redundant phrases are sometimes removed so the more relevant parts of the tag show up in the tooltip.